# How to add voice call feature to facebook page from messenger

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am currently developing a facebook messenger bot.

There is one feature that I want to add to my bot--voice call.

Is there a way to allow users to call my page when I update the phone number on my app page?

Best case would be putting calling button in menu or upper right corner where setting button is at.

Thank you in advance.